# How to protect high-speed SPI from ESD

Tags: spi, transient-suppression

I want to use the following screen with an ESP32 IC.

The screen is controlled via SPI. I want to know how do I prevent ESD from damaging the ESP32?

I have created the following schematic, which uses a series resistance and a TVS diode. I know the TVS diode needs to have a very low capacitance in order to prevent any sort of noise caused by the prolonged turn on and turn off times.

Is this sufficient to protect the ESP32 from ESD? Or do I need more precise ESD protection for SPI?

[image]

Comment: Depends on what kind of ESD you are expecting and how fast the SPI edges are. High speed ESD is tricky. But you say you want to use it with a screen? On the same PCB? If so, then why do you need ESD protection at all? There's also more to ESD than just throwing on diodes. Of course, there is tight routing, but there is also sending the ESD to a chassis plane which is connected to the circuit ground, but is distinct from it, etc.

Comment: Also, you only normally try and protect things against ESD that the end user will be casually poking around in. So unless you're expecting a lot of plugging and unplugging of this screen it may be pointless.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes the screen will be on the PCB but it is soldered using 2.54 pitch male headers. So it will be exposed. So someone may touch it on the exposed headers which will send the transient to the main PCB (esp32). Let's not get started on the PCB because that is a sperate question all together. For now I want to get the schematic correct

Comment: You have to be practical here. Because if someone could touch the exposed header on the PCB they could also touch anywhere else on the PCB. If that's what you're worried about stick it in an enclosure, otherwise you're just splitting hairs about protecting the SPI header from ESD.

Comment: @DKNguyen fair point but I should atleast still protect the inputs Goin gto the esp32 right? Cost for once is not a restraint... So adding protection is better than not having any protection

Comment: @DKNguyen what on the PCB should one protect from ESD?

Comment: I don't think so. The only things I would protect on an exposed PCB are user switches, knobs, and buttons and jacks. Things that are intentionally poked at in use, not things that are poked at only when the board is being dissected or operated. A screen is a fairly permanent fixture.

Comment: Start shopping. It's not hard to find ESD protection devices designed to be used on 10 Gbps USB lines. The same companies that make those will have slightly more effective devices with slightly higher capacitance to fit your SPI application.

Answer (score -1):

The ICs SPI pins should already be protected against HBM ESD.